# Infinite Loop Event Handler Pairs

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two views that have an event handler in the delegates that get called any time any interaction occurs. In each event hander I'd like it so it performs an interaction on the other view. The issue here is that I run into an infinite loop of back and forth calls on the event handlers i.e. when one does an interaction on the other, it triggers its event handler, and so on. Is there a way around this?

Here is the delegate method. view1 and view2 are the two views. Position is a custom class used to update positions of each view.

```
-(void) viewDelegate: (UIView*) dView didChangePosition: (Position*) newPosition {
    if( dView == view1 ){
        [view2 moveToPosition: newPosition];
    }else{
        [view1 moveToPosition: newPosition];
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please post your code. It sounds like you need to generally rethink your design strategy, though.

Comment: Check if the old and new positions are the same?

Comment: The issue with that approach is that the position is updated continuously like with a panning gesture, so there is delay between when the position in one view is modified and when the event handler for the other view called.

Comment: You should post the code for the other half of the interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of `viewDelegate:didChangePosition:` you could save the delegate of `view1` and/or `view2` to local variables, and then `nil` out the actual delegate properties.  You can then freely call `moveToPosition:` or any other code that would generate a delegate callback.  At the end of the method simply restore the delegates to the previously saved values.